# relationship between number of wavelet decomposition level and noise level

Tags: noise, wavelet, denoising

I am studying wavelet theory by myself and hope to use wavelet to denoise images. I write one matlab program to watch denoised image.

```
Gray = ones(512, 512, 'uint8');
Gray = Gray.*128;
Gray = imnoise(Gray, 'gaussian', 0, 0.01);
[cA1, cH1, cV1, cD1] = dwt2(Gray,  'db1');
[cA2, cH2, cV2, cD2] = dwt2(cA1/2, 'db1');
[cA3, cH3, cV3, cD3] = dwt2(cA2/2, 'db1');
[cA4, cH4, cV4, cD4] = dwt2(cA3/2, 'db1');
[cA5, cH5, cV5, cD5] = dwt2(cA4/2, 'db1');
figure; imshow(cA1/2, [0, 255]);
figure; ismhow(cA2/2, [0, 255]);
figure; ismhow(cA3/2, [0, 255]);
figure; ismhow(cA4/2, [0, 255]);
figure; ismhow(cA5/2, [0, 255]);
```

I find cA3 contains a lot of noise even if three decompositions have been performed. If I increase noise level, I need to perform more decomposition to obtain one smooth image in the approximation coefficients. If number of wavelet decomposition level is big, modifications of detail coefficients of high decomposition level will affect a lot of pixels and edges may be smoothed. I try to change wavelet family,but the problem still occurs. 
By the way, the function dwt2 seems to magnify the values of approximation coefficients by 2. Why does dwt2 behave like that?

Comment: Common wavelet denoising methods work by performing the wavelet transform for multiple scales, setting small coefficients to 0, then *reconstructing* the original image. All you code is doing here is displaying the low pass component of each scale of the wavelet decomposition.

Comment: Thanks. I understand wavelet denoising process. My question is that how many decompositions is requirement if one noisy image is given. What factors will determine the number of decompositions?

Comment: It depends on the image I guess, but I find that as you go up in scale (more low pass) the SNR goes down. I'm guessing that at some scale the noise is so low that all of the coefficients are above the noise value and so none get attenuated. It would therefore not make sense to go past this scale. That is just a guess though. In my work I use 4 scales for 256 x 256 image and 5 for a 512 x 512 image...

Comment: If 5 scales are used for a 512 x 512 image, regions with size of 32x32 will become one pixel. If the coefficients are shrinked at highest scale, it will affect 1024 pixels at the original scale. If edges are contained in the 32x32 regions, edges may be smoothed. Does that happen?

Comment: not really, because those 32 x 32 parts contain the low frequency part of the edge, all the high frequency stuff is in the previous scales.

Comment: From your experience,  what is the relationship between different thresholds for different decomposition level? I guess the threshold will become smaller as the scale goes up.

Comment: I can give you an example, for one of my techniques using simoncelli-type wavelets with subsampling by 2, my thresholds worked out to be [0.178, 0.08 0.04 0.02 0.01] for additive Gaussian noise. The last four are simply half of each other, which makes sense because the kernel pass band is half of the previous one and thus contains half the noise energy. The first one is a bit higher, because the first scale is a high pass filter (not a band pass) and so contains a bit more of the spectrum.

Comment: Simple method is to just pick thresholds based on the noise level. Better techniques use spatial and inter-scale information as well. E.g. if the next scale up has a high coefficient for a particular location, then lower the threshold on the current scale for that location, as it is likely that it is part of structure rather than noise.

Comment: I think one of the most famous wavelet methods is BLS-GSM

Comment: @geometrikal Your replies are valuable. I just began to use wavelet to denoise images. Do you think that whether choice of wavelet family is important. Do you use a local threshold or global threshold? The noise level cross entire image maybe not constant. How do you deal with this issue?

Comment: Have a look at this paper, it has a very quick comparison at the end http://bigwww.epfl.ch/publications/pad1401.pdf    I use a global threshold with some specially designed wavelets (unpublished) but best results come from comparing values between scales and in the surrounding pixel. With noise that varies across an image you would have to do a local estimate of the noise amount and vary the thresholds accordingly.

Comment: As for more detailed, probably have to hit the literature. I have only been looking at this for a couple of months as I wanted to try some denoising myself, so my method is quite basic (global threshold + some special wavelets). Two methods I implemented using code I found online were BLS-GSM and SURE-LET. you should be able to find some code. I also stumbled upn this site: https://www.ceremade.dauphine.fr/~peyre/matlab/wavelets/content.html

Comment: BLS-GSM (if I have worked it out correctly) uses the surrounding pixels in some kind of Gaussian mixture model to determine the threshold. SURE-LET uses "Stein's Unbiased Risk Estimator" (SURE) to tweak the thresholds based on responses from each scale. I think in the papers they manually put in the Gaussian noise standard deviation to set the thresholds, but there are ways of estimating the noise variance using the median for example.